# How to remove grey background from Label in CustomTkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Hi guys i need help i can't solve this, in the photo attached i marked with arrows the grey background border around the button, i'm using a custom tkinter button. How to remove that? I know that with a grey background it disappears but i prefer an image for background as you can see in the photo. The only solution i found is to set the "corner_radius" to 0, but i prefer to use a 20 value for example in order to custom my buttons to be in a more circle shape, how to remove the grey background? Here is my code obviously you can't run it because you don't have the background image saved in your pc but you get the idea, the button is the "bottone_crea_promemoria" variable in the last lines of code

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import customtkinter
from ctypes import windll
def promemoria():
    print('viva la gnocca')
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
with open('C:\\Users\\quaranta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\promemoria.txt') as file_testo:
    contenuto = file_testo.read()
print(contenuto)
if contenuto == '':
    win = Tk()
    #win.resizable(False,False)
    win.title('Promemoria')
    win.configure(bg='#2B2B2B')
    trasparente = PhotoImage(file="trasparente.png")
    win.iconphoto(True, trasparente)
    immagine_cancella = Image.open('dontforget.png')
    immagine_cancella = immagine_cancella.resize((600, 450))
    immagine_cancella = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=immagine_cancella)
    sfondo = Label(win,image=immagine_cancella)
    sfondo.place(x=0,y=0)
    etichetta_promemoria = Label(win,text=' Promemoria ',font=('Courier',17),bg='orange',fg='black',relief='solid',borderwidth=1)
    etichetta_promemoria.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(25,0),pady=(20,0),sticky=W)
    etichetta_titolo = Label(win,text=' Titolo ',font=('Courier',12),bg='#006653',fg='white',relief='solid',borderwidth=1)
    etichetta_titolo.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,padx=(145,0),pady=(30,0))
    campo_titolo = Entry(win, relief='flat', borderwidth=4, font=('Courier', 12), width=30, highlightthickness=2,
    highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
    campo_titolo.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=(8,0))
    etichetta_descrizione = Label(win, text=' Descrizione ', font=('Courier', 12), bg='#006653', fg='white', relief='solid',borderwidth=1)
    etichetta_descrizione.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W,padx=(145,0),pady=(45,0))
    campo_descrizione = Entry(win, relief='flat', borderwidth=4, font=('Courier', 12), width=30, highlightthickness=2,
    highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
    campo_descrizione.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(8, 0))
    etichetta_data = Label(win, text=' Data ', font=('Courier', 12), bg='#006653', fg='white', relief='solid',borderwidth=1)
    etichetta_data.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W,pady=(40,0),padx=(135,0))
    campo_data = Entry(win, relief='flat', borderwidth=4, font=('Courier', 12), width=10, highlightthickness=2,
    highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
    campo_data.grid(row=6, column=0,sticky=W,pady=(8, 0),padx=(110.5,0))
    etichetta_ore = Label(win, text=' Ore ', font=('Courier', 12), bg='#006653', fg='white', relief='solid',
    borderwidth=1)
    etichetta_ore.grid(row=5, column=0,pady=(40,0),padx=(400,0),sticky=W)
    campo_ore = Entry(win, relief='flat', borderwidth=4, font=('Courier', 12), width=10, highlightthickness=2,
    highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
    campo_ore.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(8, 0), padx=(372.3, 0))
    bottone_crea_promemoria = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=win,text='Crea promemoria',text_font = ('Courier',16,'bold'),width=260,border_width=2,border_color='black',fg_color='green',text_color='white',corner_radius=20,hover_color='#006A00',command=promemoria)
    bottone_crea_promemoria.grid(row=7,column=0,pady=30,padx=170)
    win.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
    campo_titolo.focus_set()
    win.mainloop()
else:
    win2 = Tk()
    win2.geometry('300x300')
    win2.mainloop()
```

Comment: The gray background cannot not be removed because tkinter widget (`customtkinter` inherits from tkinter widget) does not support transparent background.

Comment: @acw1668 Hi thanks for the answer now i understand, do you know if i can remove the background with an other GUI system like PyQt5 ? Even if it seems more complicated compared to Tkinter, maybe PyQt5 is more advanced

Answer (score -1):

You can set manual background color.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).